# How to prevent race condition in scheduler thats calls async function in in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency

I have a function

```
  @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "2000")
  public void processPendingDownloadRequests() {
          List<DownloadRequest> downloadRequests = downloadRequestService.getPendingDownloadRequests();
          for (int i = 0; i < downloadRequests.size(); i++) {
              DownloadRequest downloadRequest = downloadRequests.get(i);
              processDownloadRequest(downloadRequest);
          }

      }
  }
```

This will retrieve all download requests from the DB that are in the Pending state. Which is just a enum in the downloadrequest table.

```
    @Async
    public void processDownloadRequest(DownloadRequest downloadRequest) {
        accountProfileProcessor.run(downloadRequest);
    }
```

Inside the accountProfileProcessor is where the state of the downloadRequest changes to InProgress.

The race conditions comes when the @Scheduled function runs and picks up downloadRequests that have been submitted for Async jobs but the status hasn't been switched to inProgress yet. How can I avoid this?

I tried to only run the code inside the @Scheduled function if the @Async taskexecutor queue was empty but could not get it to work

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to help.  For example, where is "inProgress" status maintained?  And, when do the requests get removed from the pending-download-request-list?

Comment: Most likely, it will be necessary to keep track of the state of each download-request.  Explicitly update the state of the request in the "processDownloadRequest" method, and check the existing state before calling `accountProfileProcessor.run`.  Make sure to check-and-update atomically.

Comment: @ash Sorry, I updated my question. The status is maintained in the download request table. The status is set to inProgress inside the Async task (accountProfileProcessor). The problem is that if the Scheduler runs before the Async task managed to change the status, then it will create another async task.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a typical race condition.  There are more considerations.  For example, does each download task have a unique identifier?  And will only one instance of this application being attempting to execute the pending downloads - or will there be more (as in a "horizontally scaled" application cluster)?

Comment: @ash Yes each downloadrequest has a unique identifier as its all being grabbed from the table. One instance of this application will execute the pending downloads but the one function will spawn multiple threads.

Comment: This is a scenario where (persistent) message queues are really helpful. You put new requests into the queue and let worker threads process them concurrently.

Comment: Message queues come with caveats - such as message redelivery.

Comment: Which is exactly what you need for this (i.e. a queue with at-least-once semantics) in my opinion. If one worker dies, the message needs to be redelivered. All of this cannot be easily solved with `@Async`, because what happens if a downloading thread dies? You would need yet another scheduled task to restart the failed downloads.

Comment: So I agree that more complex requirements would lead to the need for a more complex solution.  With that said, the Op hasn't introduced those requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will prevent two concurrent attempts to download the same resource.

Note that if there is a need to make sure that subsequent attempts to execute the same download are not repeated, some form of tracking that completion for a longer time is needed, with the need to somehow prevent memory leak (i.e. don't keep all complete id's in memory indefinitely).

```
private Set<String> activeDownloads = new HashSet<>();

@Async
public void processDownloadRequest(DownloadRequest downloadRequest) {
    synchronized(this.activeDownloads) {
        if (this.activeDownloads.contains(downloadRequest.getId()) {
            // Duplicate download attempt - log it?
            return;
        } else {
            this.activeDownloads.put(downloadRequest.getId());
        }
    }


    try {
        accountProfileProcessor.run(downloadRequest);
    } finally {
        synchronized(this.activeDownloads) {
            this.activeDownloads.remove(downloadRequest.getId());
        }
    }
}
```